# How can we install lethe on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04

Lethe was once a very useful utility that enabled users to freeze the entire Ubuntu partition. There were instructions posted for installing Lethe on Ubuntu 14.04 which continued to work until the 16.10 release.

**Can anyone provide an update to the instructions for installing Lethe ([last posted here](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/90188-install-lethe-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)) that will work on Ubuntu 18.04 and derivatives.**

Apparently, there have been changes beginning with the 17.04 release that has made the hack used for Ubuntu 14.04 ineffective.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You found very interesting peace of software.
Having equivalent of Faronics Deep Freeze on Ubuntu will be great.

Let's start with downloading of the software:

```
wget https://kent.dl.sourceforge.net/project/lethe/lethe/0.3x/lethe_0.34_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./lethe_0.34_all.deb
```

But it will not install with error:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
/etc/grub.d/09_lethe: 22: .: Can't open /usr/lib/grub/update-grub_lib
dpkg: error processing package lethe (--configure):
 installed lethe package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lethe
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

We need to recreate this file from previous Ubuntu version, or maybe Debian Wheezy (see [this link from packages.debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=wheezy&arch=any&mode=path&searchon=contents&keywords=update-grub_lib)):

```
cat <<\EOF | sudo tee /usr/lib/grub/update-grub_lib
# stub for new grub-mkconfig_lib
# Copyright (C) 2007,2008  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
#
# GRUB is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# GRUB is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with GRUB.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

prefix="/usr"
exec_prefix="${prefix}"
datarootdir="${prefix}/share"

. "${datarootdir}/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib"

grub_warn "update-grub_lib is deprecated, use grub-mkconfig_lib instead"
EOF
```

and make it executable

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/grub/update-grub_lib
```

then install package again:

```
sudo apt-get install ./lethe_0.34_all.deb
```

then you should disable AppArmor to get NetworkManager and other stuff working on freezed system:

```
sudo sed -i "s/aufs=tmpfs$/aufs=tmpfs apparmor=0/" /etc/lethe/09_lethe /etc/grub.d/09_lethe
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot and enjoy:

[image: GRUB, freezed with Lethe]

> $ cat /proc/cmdline
>      BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-33-generic root=UUID=2772ff62-4902-4409-a588-cffebbf33209 ro quiet splash **aufs=tmpfs apparmor=0**

I have tested this method on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS: after installation of Lethe I booted new system, created new file, then rebooted and can't find the file in place. So it really works!

Comment: Thank you for your instructions. I followed them and installed Lethe successfully.

*There were two error messages during boot:*
 
*/scripts/local-bottom/lethe: line 77: source: not found*  

*cat: can't open '/aufs/ro/etc/rc.local': No such file or directory*  

The second error message is removed by follow [these instructions](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd). I don't know how to remove the first error as the "source" appears to be present. Perhaps I'm misinterpreting something.

Comment: I have simply ignored both warnings, the Lethe seems to do all needed job. So you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent a while to try and wrap this software to something...*user-friendly*. I finally came up with something like this - https://github.com/TheArqsz/deep-freezer.
It uses Lethe 0.34 package and fixes some obvious errors. It changes grub entries that Lethe provides to something nicer. User has access to basic, non-persistent workspace and its persistent version so changes can be made.

[Example grub entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNYBP.png)

I tested this script under Ubuntu 20.04 and 18.04.

Comment: Comment https://askubuntu.com/a/1083416/1187460 was very useful so big thanks to its author