# Disable Lethe read-only freezed drive on 18.04

Tags: grubrescue, drive, read-only

I have installed [Lethe](http://lihuen.linti.unlp.edu.ar/index.php/Gu%C3%ADa_de_instalaci%C3%B3n_de_Lethe) on Xubuntu 18.04 to block all changes a user can do as per [How can we install lethe on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083354/how-can-we-install-lethe-on-ubuntu-18-04)

How to return to normal boot and normal read-write?

Not uninstall, but just enter for an update or another addition.

I have single OS but I haven't any GRUB.

I try repair GRUB, but the only thing I can get is the minimal grub with this message:

> Minimal BASH like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

If reboot started but with read-only drive.

How can I unlock this?
without full grub or just with minimal grub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in this way.

If I press [Esc] too soon, I got the GRUB minimal BASH,
but if I don't press anything, the system start in the right way (but with Lethe and so with the Read-Only Drive)

So I should modify the grub:

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak

sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and have something like this, with STYLE COUNTDOWN and TIMEOUT greater than 0:

> GRUB_DEFAULT=0
>
> GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=**countdown**
>
> GRUB_TIMEOUT=**10**
>
> GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
>
> # GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
>
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
>
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

and after launch the classic

```
sudo update-grub
```

but I have to enter just a second or with a Live USB or in **not** Read-Only mode.

So with GRUB minimal BASH, just digit

```
normal
```

and immediatly start to press repeatedly [ESC] to reach the GRUB 2 menu.

Here simply by selecting *Advanced options for Ubuntu* you can launch the normal mode for modify and update the grub mode, to have more than 0 second to choose this line.